# Raphael JS: How to get Raphael element from Dom object(Element.node)?

Tags: javascript, raphael, jquery-svg

I try to use Raphael's node function to get a DOM object and add one event handler for context menu.
However I need to get the Raphael element from the DOM object's event handler?

To make it clear, the sample code should looks like

```
var circle = paper.circle(100, 100, 100);
var domObject = circle.node;
var ele = domObject.get(0).raphael; // It's required in the domObject's event handler
```

Does anyone know how can achive it?

Comment: Hi, Dan.  Is there any particular reason you're not using Raphael's `click`, `hover`, or `mouse*` functions for event handling?  There's no reason you shouldn't write your own, but I must warn you that the pattern you're describing above -- linking dom objects and javascript objects circularly -- is a veritable recipe for memory leaks.

Comment: I agree with kevin ... you even have the eve() functionality in Raphael to link custom events ...

Comment: Thank Kevin and Aukhan, I tried it because I want to add context menu for Raphael Element. The context menu I tried to use(http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/09/jquery-context-menu-plugin/) seems required a DOM object... Forgive my naive questions, since I'm not familiar with Raphael JS or javascript. So again, is there any good way to add a context menu for Raphael Element? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Very little additional work is required to make this work directly.  Assuming you have your jquery contextMenu resources (js, css, any images) all available and a Raphael paper `paper`:

```
var x = 200, y = 200, r = 100, fs = 36;
var circle = paper.circle( x, y, r ).attr( { fill: 'red', 'fill-opacity': 0.5 } );
var label = paper.text( x, y, "CLICK" ).attr( { fill: 'white', 'fill-opacity': 0.75, 'font-size': fs, 'font-weight': 800 } );
var set = paper.set( circle, label );
$(set.node).contextMenu( { menu: 'myMenu' } );
```

You can see this code [mocked up at my website](http://voidblossom.com/testContextMenus.php).  There are a few issues with the context menu conflicting with my css, but you can see the basic functionality is there.

Comment: Kevin, what if I don't have jQuery?